# aspose pdf Generator for Chinese character

Tags: c#, sql, pdf

I am using Chinese characters including HTML tag like this  政府关系(bold with under line)am not using Arial Unicode MS(bold with under line), please suggest me how it will take font automatically in Aspose PDF Generator. I tried this:

```
Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf pdf1 = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf();
pdf1.IsTruetypeFontMapCached = true;
pdf1.TruetypeFontMapPath = @“C:\Windows\Fonts”;
pdf1.SetUnicode();
pdf1.TextInfo.IsUnicode = true;
Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Row row;
Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Cell Cell;
Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Text txt;
row = GetAsposeRow(tablexyz, 5, 5, 5, 5);
Cell = GetAsposeCell(row, “White”, 1, 3);
txt = GetAsposeText("政府关系";, “blue”, 8f, false, false, false);
txt.IsHtmlTagSupported = true;
txt.IsHtml5Supported = true;
txt.IfHtmlTagSupportedOverwriteHtmlFontNames = true;
Cell.Paragraphs.Add(txt);
row.Cells.Add(Cell);
```

It supports only Arial Unicode MS font in Aspose PDF Generator. I would not prefer to use font name but it will automatically take font.

Comment: Have you tried Aspose support?